# What is the limit of a function which is not defined everywhere?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, limits

Let there be a function $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$, such that $f(x) = 1$ for all rational numbers $x$.

What's the limit of this function if $x$ tends to $0$? Does it exist and is $1$? Does it not exist? Is asking about the limit invalid here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The limit might be non-existent. If we have for example $f(x)=0$ for all irrational $x$, then the limit does not exist.

Comment: Assume that f is not defined for irrational.

Comment: Welcome, good question. I have edited your question to use math syntax (click "edit" if you want to see how) and to make a more helpful title of the question.

Comment: You are leaving "calculus" (your tag choice?) and moving to "general topology".  That has a tag, too.

Answer (score 5):

> What's the limit of this function if $x$ tends to $0$? Does it exist and is $1$? Does it not exist? Is asking about the limit invalid here?

The limit exists and equals $1$.

Values not in the domain of a function are not considered when taking the limit. For example, consider the following easier limit:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x}
$$

Now the function $\sqrt{x}$ implicitly has domain $[0, \infty)$. So, when we take this limit, we do *not* consider the values $x < 0$; we only consider $x > 0$. And so the answer is that the limit equals $0$.
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x} = 0.
$$

Going back to your example, you asked us to consider
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)
$$
where $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Because the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{Q}$, we do *not* consider irrational values of $x$ when taking the limit. So we only look at the values $x$ which are closer and closer to $0$, which are rational numbers. For such values of $x$, $f(x) = 1$. Therefore, the answer is
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 1.
$$

Comment: Isn't limit defined for a neighborhood? Neighborhood can not have points outside domain. No matter how small delta you take, you will still have points which are not in domain. As I understand, neighbourhood of a point is a set of points containing that point where one can move some amount in any direction away from that point without leaving the set.

Comment: @AnshulSinghal You take *relative* neighbourhoods (neighbourhoods in the whole space, here $\Bbb R$, intersected with the domain). Those count as neighbourhoods *in the domain* (as a subspace).

Comment: @AnshulSinghal It's exactly as Henno Brandsma says. We only consider points that are *both* in a neighborhood of the limit point *and also* in the domain of the function.

Answer (score 2):

The limit is $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 1$ because whatever $\varepsilon$ you take, for any $\delta >0$ we have that $f[\mathbb{Q} \cap (-\delta, \delta)] =\{1\} \subseteq (1-\varepsilon, 1+\varepsilon)$, so we always get $1$ (so $\varepsilon$-close to $1$ ) for all $x$ nearby $0$ where $f$ is defined. It's irrelevant where $f$ is not defined, as long as we have domain points $\neq 0$ that are arbitarily close to $0$. Otherwise a limit to $0$ wouldn't make sense anyway.

So also $\lim_{x \to \pi} f(x)=1$ for similar reasons.