# Continuity of a certain piecewise function

Tags: limits, continuity

Given the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2, & x<1 \\
2x-1, & x\geq3 
\end{cases}$$
May I say $f$ is continuous at $x=3$? My question is basically about the fact
$$\lim_{x\to3^{-}}f(x)$$
doesn't exist.

Comment: Do I correctly understand, that your function is not defined in $[1,3)$?

Comment: @zkutch yes, that is it.

Comment: Your map is continuous at $3$ as you can see using [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Weierstrass_and_Jordan_definitions_(epsilon%E2%80%93delta)_of_continuous_functions) of continuity when the domain is not the whole real line. *By the way, it would be useful that you mention in your question what definition of continuity you use.* Doing so, I imagine that you'll be able to answer your question by yourself!

Comment: Then $\lim\limits_{x\to3^{-}}$ simply have no sense. You can speak about continuity only from right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the limit of a function which is not defined everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369196/what-is-the-limit-of-a-function-which-is-not-defined-everywhere). Yours is potentially a duplicate in abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the function is continuous, the limit does not need to exist for the funtion to be continuous. What continuity gives is that, *if* the right and left hand limit exist, *then* they are equal to the value of the function at that point.
The basic definition of continuity (at least which I learnt first) is the sequential definition, not the one using limits:

> Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a function. It is said to be continuous at $c\in A$, if for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ that converges to $c$, the sequence $(f(x_n))$ converges to $f(c)$.

Notice that it does not say that a sequence should exist that converges to $c$ (well, apart from the constant sequence). 
Suppose we have a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, no matter how
we define $f$, it will be continuous. Does this answer your question?